# error trying to exec 'cc1', limited options for remediation

Tags: c, linux, gcc, debian, gnu-make

I am attempting to compile a file on a Debian Linux system, and I believe there is something wrong with gcc's configuration.

```
$ gcc test.c -o test -pthread -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'test' '-pthread' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch i386-linux-gnu -iprefix ../lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/ -D_REENTRANT test.c -quiet -dumpbase test.c -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase test -version -o /tmp/ccOVllff.s
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I found cc1 at /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7.2/cc1. So I symlinked cc1 to the build directory and tried again:

```
$ ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7.2/cc1 /tmp/kernelpop/
$ gcc test.c -o test -pthread
In file included from test.c:22:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:34:21: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how to tell this compiler where its libraries are? I do not have permission to install/reinstall/reconfigure packages, so updating the system won't work for me.

Comment: You may be up a creek, but please post the _complete and unedited_ output of: `printenv`; `which gcc`; `file $(which gcc)`; `file /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7.2/cc1`; `ldd /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7.2/cc1`; and `gcc test.c -o test -pthread -v` after having symlinked cc1 into the build directory (which shouldn't have had any effect at all!)

Comment: Here is the output of those commands, @zwol https://pastebin.com/QiCeCQYq

Comment: "I do not have permission to install/reinstall/reconfigure packages" - *someone* does so, given they've locked you out, surely *they* have the responsibility to provide correctly functioning tools, yes?

Comment: Did you run `./configure` or you just used one provided by others?